# How to package a command line Python script

Tags: python, command-line, packaging

I've created a python script that's intended to be used from the command line. How do I go about packaging it? This is my first python package and I've read a bit about setuptools, but I'm still not sure the best way to do this.

---

## Solution

I ended up using [setup.py](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools) with the key configurations noted below:

```
setup(
....
    entry_points="""
[console_scripts]
mycommand = mypackage.mymodule:main
""",
....
)
```

Here's a good [example](http://github.com/jsmits/github-cli/blob/c5b4166976bbf94fc3f929cc369ce094bc02b88e/setup.py) in context.

Comment: Which platform(s) will you be deploying on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Zach, given your clarification in your comment to @soulmerge's answer, it looks like what you need is to write a setup.py as per the instructions regarding the [distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html#distutils-index) -- [here](http://docs.python.org/distutils/packageindex.html) in particular is how you register on pypi, and [here](http://docs.python.org/distutils/uploading.html) on how to upload to pypi once you are registrered -- and possibly (if you need some extra functionality wrt what the distutils supply on their own) add setuptools, of which `easy_install` is part, via the instructions [here](http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py).

Comment: This answer, fortunately, is a little out of date. A good source of information now is https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/, as well as the article I have pointed out in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than using setuptools non standard way of proceeding, it is possible to directly rely on `distutils` setup's function, using the `scripts` argument, as stated here: http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts

```
from distutils import setup
setup(
    ...,
    scripts=['path/to/your/script',],
    ...
)
```

It allows you to stay compatible a) with all python versions and b) not having to rely on a setuptools as an external dependency.

Answer (score 3):

Last month, I have written an article answering exactly your question. You can find it here: http://gehrcke.de/2014/02/distributing-a-python-command-line-application/

There, I am using only currently recommended methods (twine, pure setuptools instead of distutils, the `console_scripts` key in the `entry_points` dictionary, ...), which work for Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by packaging? If it is a single script to be run on a box that already has python installed, you just need to put a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) into the first line of the file and that's it.

If you want it to be executed under Windows or on a box without python, though, you will need something external, like [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

If your question is about where to put configuration/data files, you'll need to work platform-dependently (like writing into the [registry](http://python.active-venture.com/lib/module--winreg.html) or the [home folder](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=820043)), as far as I know.

Comment: It consists of two python files. I want to package it to be distributed on PiPy, for example, and installed with easy_install.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are beginners in Python Packaging, I suggest going through this [Python Packaging Tutorial](http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/index.html).

Note about the tutorial:

> At this time, this documentation focuses on Python 2.x only, and may not be as applicable to packages targeted to Python 3.x